# Fetching latest value from core data and assigning it to a label. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've only been coding for 2 weeks now and I am trying to build a 'weights logger app'. I am saving the weights under the entity - "Weights" with attributes for "benchPress", "deadLift" etc.

I figured out how to save values. So when the user clicks save, it saves the recorded value to the array.

But I don't know how to fetch the 'latest' value and set it equal to a UILabel.

#### Image showing the entity

[image: Image showing the entity]

#### The code I have so far to fetch the result

[image: The code I have so far to fetch the result]

Any help would really be appreciated. I've been stuck on this for a while now. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Nextime please paste the code in your answer and avoid code in images! Thanks!

Comment: The first thing to do, is to read. Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) and [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-overview/). If you don't understand anything then google it. If you're still stuck then come back here. This is a big part of coding BTW. When you're a beginner you spend most of your time reading and watching videos. Welcome to the community!

Comment: You need something like a `dateAdded` attribute in your model.

Comment: are you displaying the current "latest" value on a label or something?

Comment: Yep. So when the user saves the value- quits the app and comes back. The last value saved is displayed.

Comment: Also I will continue to read around the topic as suggested :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data doesn't have any concept of "latest". It doesn't track when new data has been saved. If you need something like the most recent entry, you need to add your own field-- a date, or an integer index, or something that would indicate the correct instance to fetch.

If you added a date field named `date`, you'd get the entry with the most recent date using a fetch request something like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Weights"];
NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
fetch.sortDescriptors = @[ dateSort ];
fetch.fetchLimit = 1;
```

The result would be an array containing at most one object, which would have the most recently saved date.